# Performance & memory while saving record locally in device

Tags: ios, swift, performance

I have a query for saving data locally in the device. I have tableview with itemname on the cell. The user should be able to delete an item from the list by swiping them to the right. These should not reappear subsequently to this action either in the current session or subsequent launches of the app.

I can create an array of deleted items & store them in NSUserDefault, plist or cache. Next time of table load I will exclude these stored records.

What is the best option for doing above operation? Which one is the best (NSUserDefault, plist or cache or anything else) in terms of memory, fast operation, user interaction etc?

Comment: Totally **not** `UserDefaults`.

Comment: it depends on the data source, you shouldn't store a list of deleted items, best to store the items as a data source, probably in realm or core data and then remove the items from your data source as they are selected for deletion by the user

Answer (score 2):

### What you should use

- You might want to use [**CoreData**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata), because it can handle a large amount of data and is also very simple to use. In terms of memory and performance, it works quite well too. It also has the advantage that it can store any type of data.
- On the other hand, a very solid alternative is [**Swift Realm**](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), because it is very efficient and can also store large amounts of data. Its performance is great, I think you should consider it as an option.

---

### What you should avoid

- When it comes to **`UserDefaults`**, I think it is the worst thing to use in such a case, because it can only handle small amounts of data. It's performance is not great either, so I *strongly recommend* you *not* to use it.

---

> **Note:** Instead of storing the deleted items, you should consider saving the valid items instead, and remove the unwanted items from the data once the user chooses to delete them. Also, be careful when storing data locally and avoid saving sensitive data *unencrypted*.